# Ag-grid autoheight=true colDef property on cell renderer causes stutter

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When using ag-grid with a cell renderer which has autoHeight=true, the grid renders the rows initially with a set height that looks to be ~40 or 50px, then calculates the height and re-renders the rows with the correct height. I'm wanting to avoid the jump/stutter in the screen caused by the resize and ideally hold off rendering a given row till the height is calculated.

This defect started popping up when upgrading from v25-> v28 of ag-grid.

This [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dhthax?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-cell-renderer%2Fmy-cell-renderer.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-cell-renderer%2Fmy-cell-renderer.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fmy-cell-renderer%2Fmy-cell-renderer.component.css,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) shows an MVP of this issue. Effectively setting auto height on a cell renderer. To see the issue, you may need to cause the output to refresh (save a code change).

Comment: This should be something to report to AgGrid, as it is not a bug in your code to debug, but an issue with AgGrid's autoHeight implementation.

Comment: oops, yeah didn't go back to update it but I did open a defect with them.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the defect? I am noticing this issue as well

Comment: you can find it by searching their pipeline: https://www.ag-grid.com/pipeline/


AG-6243
[Regression] When using row autoheight, rendering rows produces a flicker as the rows change height
Currently in backlog for a while now, not sure if it'll get addressed anytime soon